# JavaScript Multi-level inheritance and isPrototypeOf

Tags: javascript, inheritance, multi-level

I have a multi-level inheritance implemented in JavaScript like below

```
function MovingObject(){

}

function Vehicle(){

}
Vehicle.prototype = Object.create(MovingObject);

function Car(){

}
Car.prototype = Object.create(Vehicle);

var c = new Car();
```

Car is child of Vehicle which in turn is child of MovingObject, so I am expecting Car to be indirect child of MovingObject.

Below statement returns true indicating Car is direct child of Vehicle

```
Vehicle.isPrototypeOf(c);
```

But, below statement does not return true

```
MovingObject.isPrototypeOf(c);
```

Any idea **why it does not return true**, and **how to get it to return true**?

Comment: It should be `Vehicle.prototype = Object.create(MovingObject.prototype)`, same with the other.

Comment: Even with Vehicle.prototype = Object.create(MovingObject.prototype), how do I write code to test is-a relationship between instance of Car and MovingObject?

Answer (score 1):

This is a common issue about JavaScript.

`MovingObject` or `Vehicle` are **constructor functions** but they're not the prototypes.

That is, you should derive using `Object.create(ConstructorFunction.prototype)` instead of just `ConstructorFunction`.

In JavaScript, even a function is an object and this is why `Object.create(...)` works when you provide a constructor function. The resulting object will have the constructor function object as prototype.

Actually you can both use the `Object.create(ConstructorFunction.prototype)` approach or you can achieve the same goal using `new`:

```
Vehicle.prototype = new MovingObject();
```

The main issue with `new` approach is that you're creating a new object using a constructor, and maybe you're adding unwanted data and behavior to the prototype:

```js
function MovingObject() {
  this.x = 11;
}

function Vehicle() {}
Vehicle.prototype = new MovingObject();

var instance = Object.create(Vehicle.prototype);

// What? instance has "x" property!!
document.getElementById("result").textContent = instance.x;
```

```html
<div id="result"></div>
```

### Update

OP said in some comment:

> Does that mean we cannot establish a true is-a relationship between
> Car and MovingObject here? If yes, how can we test it using code?
> Meaning, I want to execute some code only if Car is-a Moving object.
> How can I achieve the test?

Check and execute the following code snippet to be more clear:

```js
function A() {}

function B() {}
B.prototype = Object.create(A.prototype);

function C() {}
C.prototype = Object.create(B.prototype);

var instanceOfB = Object.create(B.prototype);
var instanceOfC = Object.create(C.prototype);

var result1 = A.prototype.isPrototypeOf(instanceOfC);
var result2 = B.prototype.isPrototypeOf(instanceOfC);
var result3 = A.prototype.isPrototypeOf(instanceOfB);

document.getElementById("result1").textContent = result1;
document.getElementById("result2").textContent = result2;
document.getElementById("result3").textContent = result3;
```

```html
<h2>A is prototype of instanceOfC?</h2>
<div id="result1"></div>
<h2>B is prototype of instanceOfC?</h2>
<div id="result2"></div>
<h2>A is prototype of instanceOfB?</h2>
<div id="result3"></div>
```

### Update 2

As @RobertRossmann has commented out on this answer, same code snippet can be implemented using the `instanceof` operator, which has the added value of being valid to check if instances are of some prototype providing the constructor function:

```js
function A() {}

function B() {}
B.prototype = Object.create(A.prototype);

function C() {}
C.prototype = Object.create(B.prototype);

var instanceOfB = Object.create(B.prototype);
var instanceOfC = Object.create(C.prototype);

var result1 = instanceOfC instanceof B;
var result2 = instanceOfC instanceof C;
var result3 = instanceOfB instanceof A;
var result4 = instanceOfC instanceof A;

document.getElementById("result1").textContent = result1;
document.getElementById("result2").textContent = result2;
document.getElementById("result3").textContent = result3;
document.getElementById("result4").textContent = result4;
```

```html
<div id="result1"></div>
<div id="result2"></div>
<div id="result3"></div>
<div id="result4"></div>
```

Comment: Does that mean we cannot establish a true is-a relationship between Car and MovingObject here? If yes, how can we test it using code? Meaning, I want to execute some code only if Car is-a Moving object. How can I achieve the test?

Comment: @AtulP I believe that my answer was answering this already, but I've updated it with a sample about your concern :)

Comment: I believe the [`instanceof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof) operator might be of use here as well - it is basically a nice syntactic sugar for recursively checking the complete prototype chain. And, it operates on instances and **constructor functions**!

Comment: @RobertRossmann Yeah... I've made the samples with `isPrototypeOf` because the OP was using it, so I could show OP that it should work...